# PHP send email with loop data

Tags: php

Hi I want to send loop data with php mail function here is my code:

```
foreach ($data['query'] as $row){
    echo $row->name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row->time;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row->dosage;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row->frequency;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row->quantity;
    echo "<br>";
}

$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Can anybody told me how I can attach foreach loop data to email message body, I mean instead of sending this text (Hello World!) in body I want to send loop data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the `$txt`:

```
$txt = "";
foreach ($data['query'] as $row){
    $txt .= $row->name;
    $txt .= "<br>";
    $txt .= $row->time;
    $txt .= "<br>";
    $txt .= $row->dosage;
    $txt .= "<br>";
    $txt .= $row->frequency;
    $txt .= "<br>";
    $txt .= $row->quantity;
    $txt .= "<br>";
}

$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Comment: Only one problem left that <br> is not working in sent mail can you help?

Comment: you have to set headers as HTML or add `$txt .= "\n";` instead of `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

Purely String Concatenation like below:

```
   $str = ''; 
   foreach ($data['query'] as $row){
      $str .= $row->name;
      $str .= "<br>";
      $str .= $row->time;
      $str .= "<br>";
      $str .= $row->dosage;
      $str .= "<br>";
      $str .= $row->frequency;
      $str .= "<br>";
      $str .= $row->quantity;
      $str .= "<br>";
    }

    $to = "somebody@example.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";
    mail($to,$subject,$str,$headers);

    $str = ''; // empty the $str again
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
    $to = "somebody@example.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = "Hello world!";
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";

    foreach ( $data['query'] as $row ) {
      $txt = $row->name;
      $txt .= "<br>";
      $txt .= $row->time;
      $txt .= "<br>";
      $txt .= $row->dosage;
      $txt .= "<br>";
      $txt .= $row->frequency;
      $txt .= "<br>";
      $txt .= $row->quantity;
      $txt .= "<br>";

      mail( $to, $subject, $txt, $headers );
    }
```

This sends a mail for every loop. It is unclear from your question if you want that. You can als collect all data, and send it as 1 email:

```
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";

foreach ( $data['query'] as $row ) {
  $txt .= $row->name;
  $txt .= "<br>";
  $txt .= $row->time;
  $txt .= "<br>";
  $txt .= $row->dosage;
  $txt .= "<br>";
  $txt .= $row->frequency;
  $txt .= "<br>";
  $txt .= $row->quantity;
  $txt .= "-- end of row<br>";

}

mail( $to, $subject, $txt, $headers );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dataArray  =   array('name','time','dosage','frequency','quantity');
$txt        =   '';
foreach ($data['query'] as $row)
{
    foreach($dataArray as $key=>$data)
    {
       $txt .= ($row->$data.'</br>');
    }
}

$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

?>
```